# Send message to Telegram through html form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, telegram, form-data

Is it possible to send [Html Form Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) (in a html page) to Telegram Api using JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can program your telegram bot and send any message using javascript (using AJAX since the telegram bot api is a web request based api).

For example, you send message to a specific user by this:

```
let tg = {
    token: "BOT_TOKEN", // Your bot's token that got from @BotFather
    chat_id: "CHAT_ID" // The user's(that you want to send a message) telegram chat id
}

/**
 * By calling this function you can send message to a specific user
 * @param {String} the text to send
 *
*/
function sendMessage(text)
{
    const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${tg.token}/sendMessage?chat_id=${tg.chat_id}&text=${text}`; // The url to request
    const xht = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xht.open("GET", url);
    xht.send();
}

// Now you can send any text(even a form data) by calling sendMessage function.
// For example if you want to send the 'hello', you can call that function like this:

sendMessage("hello");
```

Also you can use `POST` request to send data. For example:

```
function sendMessage(text)
{
    const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${tg.token}/sendMessage` // The url to request

    const obj = {
        chat_id: tg.chat_id, // Telegram chat id
        text: text // The text to send
    };

    const xht = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xht.open("POST", url, true);
    xht.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    xht.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.

```js
async function sendMessage(text)
{
    const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${tg.token}/sendMessage` // The url to request

    const obj = {
        chat_id: tg.chat_id, // Telegram chat id
        text: text // The text to send
    };

    await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(obj)
    });
}
```

---

Resources:

Telegram Bot API documentation - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api
Fetch API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
XMLHttpRequest - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: How about including the input value 
(Data)  the user typed..

Comment: Assuming i have 3 inputs. I store their values in the strings (name, email, and Text ) respectively..  how can i attach the strings while sending the message...

Comment: @Sagmar You can append any text to a message by appending any text the `text` argument in `sendMessage()`. **You have to use `+` instead of spaces in the text.** If you meant `<input>` value, then you can `sendMessage(document.querySelector('input').value);`.

Comment: @Sagmar I updated the answer on how to send a message by `POST` request. By using that, you don't have to user `+` instead of space; just you can use the normal text. POST is easy than GET since you can send json directly.

Comment: I declare and store the input values, inside the **text** variable, but on submitting the form, only the **message in the textarea** is sent.  `//Declarations 
 var name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
 var mail = document.querySelector("#mail").value;
 var message = document.querySelector("#message").value;
 
 var text = nameVal+mail+message;`

Comment: As I told you, you have to use `+` instead if space (if you are using get request). For that you can do `text = text.split(" ").join("+");`. Also, you can try sending `name`, `mail` and `message` as three messages... @Sagmar

Comment: See how i make it.. using **POST METHOD** but Only the Textarea is working [link] (https://codepen.io/sagmar/details/abYjrbg)

Comment: That happen because your `text` variable is assigned only the textarea value. Just create a one variable(`text`) by appending all those  other variables. (And I recommend not to show your bot token publicly) @Sagmar

Comment: Thanks,  by appending all did u mean `text = name+mail+message; `  ??

Comment: Yes, @Sagmar :)

Comment: I've done that! But still its not working **Only the textarea** field is sent! https://codepen.io/sagmar/details/abYjrbg

Comment: Try this code : https://pastebin.com/vR3FFeXh Modified 24th line of your code. It will work @Sagmar

Comment: Still it didnt work 

Comment: But the same code (https://pastebin.com/vR3FFeXh) works for me :( @Sagmar

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/) to send messages.

Comment: How to do that  please?

Comment: Read this documentation https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage